# How to check and correct user input when he omit the extension .exe to kill the process?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this batch to kill some process typed of course by the user and it works 5/5 when the user for example typed **Calc.exe** with the extension, but my issue now is to improve this batch in order to add automatically with this program if the user has omitted to add extension **.exe** like **Calc** without extension **.exe** will not work.

```
@Echo off & cls
Mode con cols=72 lines=7
Set TmpFile=TmpFile.txt
Set Resultat=KillResult.txt
If Exist %TmpFile% Del %TmpFile%
If Exist %Resultat% Del %Resultat%
::********************************************************************************************
:Main
Title Process Killer by Hackoo 2015
cls & color 0B
echo.
echo                Quel(s) processus voulez-vous fermer ?
echo.
set/p "process=Entrer le(s) nom(s) de(s) processus> "
cls & color 0C
Title Killing "%process%" ...
echo.
echo                       Killing "%process%" ...
echo.
echo %date% *** %time% >> %TmpFile%
For %%a in (%process%) Do Call :KillProcess %%a
Cmd /U /C Type %TmpFile% > %Resultat%
Start %Resultat%
echo.
Goto :Main
::*********************************************************************************************
:KillProcess
Taskkill /IM "%~1" /F >> %TmpFile% 2>&1
echo ***************************************************************************** >> %TmpFile% 
::*********************************************************************************************
```

So i'm focusing on this piece of code but no success !
this my little try :

```
:KillProcess
Set str=%~1
set str=%str:~-4%
echo.%str%
pause
if %str%==".exe" (Taskkill /IM "%~1" /F >> %TmpFile% 2>&1) || (Taskkill /IM "%~1.exe" /F >> %TmpFile% 2>&1)
```

So how to do that in batch ?

Thank you !

Comment: You can use `%~x1` to get the extension. If your files have never any other extension than `.exe`, you can use `"%~n1.exe"` to get the filename with `.exe`

Comment: @Wimmel Please add your comment in your answer to accept it, because it works as i expected Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your files have never any other extension than `.exe`, you can use `"%~n1.exe"` to get the filename with `.exe`.

`%~n1` is just the filename without extension. Than add `.exe`, and put quotes around it in case the filename contains a space.

But this will fail if your executable is `example.program.exe`, and the user entered `example.program`. In this case the result of `"%~n1.exe"` will be `"example.exe"`. To avoid that, you have to check if the extension is `.exe`. You can use `%~x1` to get just the extension.

See also [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Just i want to share with you the hole script with a dynamic menu, perhaps it would be helpful for other people and thank you for all your contributions ;)

(Translated some french words to english)

```
@Echo off & cls & color 0B
Mode con cols=72 lines=10
Set TmpFile=TmpFile.txt
Set Resultat=KillResult.txt
If Exist %TmpFile% Del %TmpFile%
If Exist %Resultat% Del %Resultat%
:menuLOOP
Cls & color 0B
Title Process Starter and Killer by Hackoo 2015
echo.
echo.      ==========================Menu============================
echo.
for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=_ " %%A in ('"findstr /b /c:":menu_" "%~f0""') do echo.           %%B  %%C
echo.
echo.      ==========================================================
set choice=
echo. & set /p choice=Make a choice or hit ENTER to quit: || GOTO :EOF
echo. & call :menu_[%choice%]
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[1] Start a Process
cls & color 0B
echo.
Set /p "MyProcess=Enter the process name to start it> "
echo.
echo Le processus %MyProcess% est lance ... 
Start %MyProcess%
GOTO :menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[2] Kill a Process or Multi Processes
Title Process Killer by Hackoo 2015
cls & color 0B
echo.
echo                What process do you want to kill ?
echo.
set/p "process=Enter the process name or processes names separated by a space> "
cls & color 0C
Title Killing "%process%" ...
echo.
echo                       Killing "%process%" ...
echo.
echo %date% *** %time% >> %TmpFile%
For %%a in (%process%) Do Call :KillMyProcess %%a
Cmd /U /C Type %TmpFile% > %Resultat%
Start %Resultat%
GOTO :menuLOOP
::*********************************************************************************************
:KillMyProcess
Taskkill /IM "%~n1.exe" /F >> %TmpFile% 2>&1
echo ***************************************************************************** >> %TmpFile%
exit /b 
::*********************************************************************************************
:EOF
EXIT
```

**EDIT 15/06/2015 : New Version** : Adding **Search for files** using the command **Where**

```
    @Echo off & cls & color 0B
    Mode con cols=72 lines=11
    Set TmpFile=TmpFile.txt
    Set Resultat=KillResult.txt
    If Exist %TmpFile% Del %TmpFile%
    If Exist %Resultat% Del %Resultat%
    :menuLOOP
    Mode con cols=72 lines=11
    Cls & color 0B
    Title Process Starter and Killer by Hackoo 2015
    echo(
    echo(      ==========================Menu============================
    echo(
    ::Suggestion de Walid : optimisation au niveau du parseur : utiliser deux tokens au lieu de trois
    for /f "tokens=2* delims=_ " %%A in ('"findstr /b /c:":menu_" "%~f0""') do echo(                %%A  %%B
    ::for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=_ " %%A in ('"findstr /b /c:":menu_" "%~f0""') do echo(           %%B  %%C
    echo(
    echo(      ==========================================================
    set choice=
    echo( & set /p choice=Make a choice or hit ENTER to quit: || GOTO :EOF
    echo( & call :menu_[%choice%]
    GOTO:menuLOOP
    ::********************************************************************************************
    :menu_[1] Start a Process
    cls & color 0B
    echo(
    Set /p "MyProcess=Enter the process name to start it> "
    echo(
    echo Le processus %MyProcess% est lance ... 
    Start %MyProcess%
    GOTO :menuLOOP
    ::********************************************************************************************
    :menu_[2] Kill a Process or Multi Processes
    Title Process Killer by Hackoo 2015
    cls & color 0B
    echo(
    echo                What process(es) do you want to kill ?
    echo(
    set /p "process=Enter the process name or processes names separated by a space> "
    cls & color 0C
    Title Killing "%process%" ...
    echo(
    echo                       Killing "%process%" ...
    echo(
    echo %date% *** %time% >> %TmpFile%
    For %%a in (%process%) Do Call :KillMyProcess %%a
    Cmd /U /C Type %TmpFile% > %Resultat%
    Start %Resultat%
    GOTO :menuLOOP

::********************************************************************************************
    :menu_[3] Search for files
    cls & color 0A
    echo(
    Set /p "Location=Enter the folder location where do you want to serach> "
    cls & echo(
    echo You chose this location "%Location%"
    echo(
    Set /p "FileName=Enter the file name to looking for> "
    Mode con cols=90 lines=11
    Set Tmp=Tmp.txt
    Set SearchResult=SearchResult.txt
    echo( & cls
    echo(  & echo  Please Wait for moment .... Searching for "%FileName%" on "%Location%"
    where /r "%Location%" "%FileName%" > %Tmp%
    ::Pour lire la liste en Unicode (Arabe)
    Cmd /U /C Type %Tmp% > %SearchResult%
    Del %Tmp%
    Start %SearchResult%
    GOTO :menuLOOP
    ::*********************************************************************************************
    :KillMyProcess
    Taskkill /IM "%~n1.exe" /F >> %TmpFile% 2>&1
    echo ***************************************************************************** >> %TmpFile%
    exit /b 
    ::*********************************************************************************************
    :EOF
    EXIT
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
:loopMain
set /p "process=Entrer le(s) nom(s) de(s) processus> "
if "%process:.exe=%"=="%process%" goto :loopMain
```

or

```
:loopMain
set /p "process=Entrer le(s) nom(s) de(s) processus> "
if /I not "%process:~-4%"==".exe" goto :loopMain
```

or `set "process=%process%.exe"` instead of `goto :loopMain`.

Similar approach in case of multiple names typed in: check an correct user's input in a simple `for %%a in (%process%) do ...` loop.