# How to stop a coded ui test using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, coded-ui-tests

I am running a coded ui script in infinite loop as per my requirement. I can start the coded ui test using the the mstest.exe.

I wanted to know is there any way using which I can stop the coded Ui test, any command that I can use in the batch file to stop the coded ui script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this little batch to kill any process :

```
@echo off
Title Process Killer
Mode con cols=72 lines=5 & Color 0C
set Process2Kill=mstest.exe
Taskkill /IM "%Process2Kill%" /F
pause
```

And if you want to see more features like how to start a process and how to kill one process or multiple processes at once that interact with user input with a dynamic menu you should take a look at this post ==> [How to check and correct user input when he omit the extension .exe to kill the process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823681/how-to-check-and-correct-user-input-when-he-omit-the-extension-exe-to-kill-the/30828097#30828097)

Comment: Thanks Hackoo, I will try this and update here about it.

Comment: this will prevent getting any test result