# How to Open and Close Internet Explorer from batch file?

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file, cmd, kill-process, taskkill

I Have a batch file which has to launch Internet explorer and open **www.google.com**. When the whole page loads finishing it should kill the IE process i.e. close all instances of IE in that system. My batch file has following two lines.

```
iexplore.exe "www.google.com"
taskkill /IM iexplore.exe /F
```

But after loading it is not closing the IE instance.

If I am having seperate batch file with with only single line **taskkill /IM iexplore.exe /F**. This batch file closes the IE instance.

What is going wrong in First Batch file.

P.S Batch file is in Internet Explorer folder of program files.

Comment: try with sleep before the taskkill

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why do you want to open a web page and then immediately close it?

Comment: @DavidPostill just curious to attempt that. It has nothing to do with any problem or solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't understand exactly your aim to open and to close immediately Internet explorer ? but here is an example with a sleep to show you how it does work !

```
@echo off
Title Start and Kill Internet Explorer
Mode con cols=75 lines=5 & color 0B
echo(
echo                     Launching Internet Explorer ...
Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "www.google.com"
:: Sleep for 20 seconds
Timeout /T 20 /NoBreak>NUL
echo(
echo            Hit any Key to kill all instances of Internet Explorer
Pause>nul
Cls & Color 0C
echo(
echo              Killing Internet Explorer Please wait for a while ...
Taskkill /IM "iexplore.exe" /F
pause
```

And if you want to see more features like how to start a process and how to kill one process or multiple processes at once that interact with user input with a dynamic menu you should take a look at this post ==> [How to check and correct user input when he omit the extension .exe to kill the process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823681/how-to-check-and-correct-user-input-when-he-omit-the-extension-exe-to-kill-the/30828097#30828097)

Try this alternative without confirmation from the user input :

```
@echo off
Title Start and Kill Internet Explorer
Mode con cols=75 lines=5 & color 0B
echo(
echo                     Launching Internet Explorer ...
Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "www.google.com"
:: Sleep for 10 seconds, you can change the SleepTime variable
set SleepTime=10
Timeout /T %SleepTime% /NoBreak>NUL
Cls & Color 0C
echo(
echo              Killing Internet Explorer Please wait for a while ...
Taskkill /IM "iexplore.exe" /F
```

Comment: I dont need any manual help in this.It is asking for confirmation.Can we do without promting user to click any key?